# How to add to a class a string with two integers and show the sum

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

Greeting fellow programmers!

I am currently studying software development (I started not a month ago) and I have a problem that needs a solution. Underneath you can find the code and as you can see, the method WriteNumber needs help. I need to write the code in a way that when I run the program, on the console screen the following two lines will be shown: 
Hello World!
81
The Main method code cannot be changed and also I cannot add more methods to the class Calculator so the code needs to be done only within the WriteNumbers method. I have tried a lot of things but I am still grasping how everything works so any help is welcome! Thank you in advance for your time.

```
Namespace CalculatorTest
{

class Calculator
{
    public static string WriteText (string input)
    {
        return "" + input;
    }
    public static string WriteNumber()
    {


    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = Calculator.WriteText("Hello World!");
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        string n = Calculator.WriteNumber(53 + 28);
        Console.WriteLine(n);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: For `WriteText` you're passing input to the method. You're not doing that for `WriteNumber`. What do you need to pass in and how can you transform that to a string you can return?

Comment: Please at least give an attempt and then ask questions if you get stuck. Don't just post a homework assignment here and ask how to do it.

Comment: @TomislavBijelic, this is not that difficult either way are you familiar with the Debugger.. if you step through the code you can quickly figure out what you need to do.. also in the mean time read up on how to use the `string.Format` function it can save you a world of headaches when it comes to formatting for example `Hello World {0}` you could have had the `ConsoleWriteLine(string.Format(s, n))`

Comment: @itsme86 Unfortunately my friend, I cannot give you an attempt because I was, and I mean literally, 4 hours stuck on this example. I want to learn and understand programming. I have a master degree in economics but since employment is very hard to find in that area in my country, I literally put all my hopes and efforts in programming as I want to go and work abroad. So also trust me that I know that by just copy/pasting and not actually trying will get me only so far :) Though I appreciate what you said because everyone needs to try their best before asking for help. Peace

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you for your advice! We haven't reached how to use string.Format yet but I will definitely look it up on how it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to do your homework for you to just be copied/pasted, hopefully I can give you some hints...

Notice how the method is being invoked:

```
Calculator.WriteNumber(53 + 28)
```

The `53 + 28` part happens first, then the *result* of that operation is passed to the method.  That result, naturally, is `81`.  What's important about that is its type, which is an integer.

So, reasonably, the method signature needs to accept an `int` as a parameter.  This would be done *very* similarly to how the other method accepts a `string` as a parameter:

```
public static string WriteText(string input)
```

---

What, then, does that method need to do with that input?  Well, it's only a single value, so there aren't any calculations to be performed on it.  It would *appear* that the method simply needs to return the value as a `string`.  (It's your homework so you tell me, is that correct?)

This can be done with exactly two things:

- Calling `.ToString()` on the value
- Using the `return` keyword to return the result of that operation

(Note: The `.ToString()` operation does something very intuitive on value types, such as `int` or `double` or `bool`.  As you progress into using reference types, you're going to find that it does something very different.  Any time you have a custom class on which you want to call `.ToString()`, you'll need to override the `.ToString()` method on that class first.)

Comment: Ohhh, such a basic mistake on my part (/facepalm). I completely forgot that the 53 + 28 are going to be added first THEN passed on to the method. That solved everything, thank you! I was in a wrong mind set the whole time because I was trying to figure what function to type in order to sum those two numbers in the WriteNumber method.

Answer (score 0):

Please read David's answer, it's important that you make the effort to understand why this works the way it does.  That being said:

```
public static string WriteNumber(int number)
{
   return number.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your valuable input but special thanks to David because he showed where I made my error. I forgot that the two numbers in the main function will be summed up FIRST and THEN forwarded to the method in the class Calculator. After that got cleared up, it was easy to understand what to do (basically adjust the type of the input parameter to int).

```
namespace CalculatorTest
{

class Calculator
{
    public static string WriteText (string input)
    {
        return "" + input;
    }
    public static string WriteNumber(int sumOfNumbers)
    {
        return "" + sumOfNumbers;                 
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = Calculator.WriteText("Hello World!");
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        string n = Calculator.WriteNumber(53 + 28);
        Console.WriteLine(n);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}